# Unable to set background color of my view after i undo drawn path

Tags: android, view, paint, android-canvas

This is my code for undo of drawn path..

```
static ArrayList<Bitmap> undoimage = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
size = MyPainting.undoimage.size() - 1; // Undoimage is arraylist
MyPainting.undoimage.remove(size);
sizee = MyPainting.undoimage.size();

for (int i = 0; i < sizee; i++){
    Bitmap undo = MyPainting.undoimage.get(i);
    MyPainting.mCanvas.drawBitmap(undo, 0, 0, mPaint);
}
```

MyPainting is the name of class where i am extending View Class
Undo is done perfectly.But once i do undo, i am unable to change the background color of my view. i am changing my view color like this :

```
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
view.invalidate();
```

it also works fine but if i click undo and then i set background color, background is not changed and when i clear all that bg color is reflected after clearing screen.
Please Help...

Comment: can you paste any error or little more detail about code

Comment: i am not getting any error but when i set background color after doing undo process, background color does not change.

Comment: can you place complete code so that i could help you.

Comment: what is view? how you are using canvas to change background it little bit unclear.If you want you can post and when i read it then again delete

Comment: <com.mit.MyPainting
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="415dp" />                                                                      view i am using from my xml that i have shown juz.On touch event i am storing bitmap in undoimage(Array list of Bitmap), when undo is clicked , i am removing one size less than stored, that code also i have mentioned

Comment: @Sameer my code is at http://pastebin.com/27HVS86Q i need some thing if user moves outside the drawn path than clear or reset that path it works with bug plz can u help me as u have worked on this type of apps